# Iterative process causing segmentation faults

Tags: recursion

Often in Mathematica, I program in some iterative process (say, some random walk) in order to find maxima. I usually write some hacky code involving iteration, and using the construction:

```
a[m_, k_] := a[m, k] = ...
```

In order to remember previous computations. Because I want to run it many times, say 100,000, I then evaluate

```
$RecursionLimit = Infinity
```

However, even in this setting, the following thing happens. If I type:

```
a[1000, 30]

a[2000,30]

a[3000,30]
```

It works and produces a reasonable answer. On the other hand, if at the start I typed:

```
a[3000, 30]
```

I get a segmentation fault. I have no idea what is causing this. I *can* get the answer I want simply by typing a[1000*k,30] by hand for 100 values of k, but there must be a better way. The version of Mathematica I am using is:

**Mathematica 11.3.0 Kernel for Linux x86 (64-bit) Copyright 1988-2018 Wolfram Research, Inc.**

I can reproduce the same result using **Mathematica 10.4.1.0 on Mac OS X x86.**

Here is a sample code in which exhibits the behavior above (with the parameters as given). Apologies it is a little long as I wasn't quite sure how to simplify it and still get the same behavior. (I have, however, experienced similar behavior before on quite different setups.)

---

```
dd[m_] :=
Product[N[Abs[m[[i]] - m[[j]]], 20], {i, 1, Length[m] - 1}, {j,
i + 1, Length[m]}]^(1/Binomial[Length[m], 2]);


a[0, l_] :=
a[0, l] = Table[(RandomReal[1/100] + RandomReal[1/100]*I), {k, 1, l}];


b[n_, l_] :=
b[n, l] =
RandomSample[a[n, l]] +
Table[KroneckerDelta[k - 1] (RandomReal[1/10] + RandomReal[1/10]*I), {k, 1,
 l}];


c[n_, l_] :=
c[n, l] =
If[Abs[(1/b[n, l][[1]])] > 2,
b[n, l], a[n, l]];

a[n_, l_] :=
a[n, l] =
If[dd[c[n - 1, l]] > dd[a[n - 1, l]], c[n - 1, l], a[n - 1, l]];

$RecursionLimit = Infinity
```

Comment: No, I used the parameters specified in the question. I'd venture you'd blow the stack eventually, and with recursion limit at infinity, that can crash MMA / kernel.

Just stick it in a Do loop and step up to whatever large value you want in chunks, so the precomputed results get used... a[50000,30] evaluated fine using such a method. 

Better yet, what exactly are you trying to accomplish here? There may be a better way, but few will want to reverse engineer the goal from the code...